# Rails 5 RESTful API with advanced relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I have many resources with advanced relations (habtm/hm/hmt etc..), everything you can imagine, but now it's time to write a beautiful routing for this API.
The problem is, I can't fin the best practices about nested resource + advanced relations ro do my routing, here is what I am trying to do:

Here are my models with the concerned relations

```rb
# app/models/candidate.rb
class Candidate < ApplicationRecord
  include Sociable, Locatable

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :sourcing_accounts
  has_many :accounts, through: :sourcing_accounts
  has_many :users, through: :sourcing_accounts
end

# app/models/sourcing_account.rb
class SourcingAccount < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :candidate
  belongs_to :user
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Sociable

  has_many :candidates
  has_many :campaigns
  has_many :sourcing_account
end
```

For this example, I am willing to permit to create a relation between a `Candidate` and a `User` by creating a `SourcingAccount`.

```rb
resources :candidates do
  resources :accounts
  resources :users, only: [:index] do
    post :remove
    post :add
  end
end
```

It generates:

```
v1_candidate_user_remove POST   /v1/candidates/:candidate_id/users/:user_id/remove(.:format) api/v1/users#remove {:subdomain=>"api", :format=>:json}
   v1_candidate_user_add POST   /v1/candidates/:candidate_id/users/:user_id/add(.:format)    api/v1/users#add {:subdomain=>"api", :format=>:json}
```

I did not found anything about this. Is there best practices ???
If not, what do you think would be the best for this case ?

Without precisions, Rails wants to route this to users#remove and users#add, which I think is totally wrong. These actions must not belong to the users controller.

Bonus:

What should look like a polymorphic route to create an `Account` belonging to 2 other models (with presence validation) the 2 models are `Source` and the other one is polymorphic `[Candidate,User] # for example`, (they are `Sociable` models)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best practice is to never* nest resources more than one level and only nest where the nesting is necessary or provides context.

Remember than any record with a unique id or uid can be fetched directly without context. So nesting member routes needlessly will make your API overcomplicated and really wordy.

```
DELETE /as/:id
is a lot better than
DELETE /as/:a_id/bs/:b_id/c/:id # Are you kidding me!
```

Lets say take a classical microblogging app as an example:

```
class User
  has_many :posts, foreign_key: 'author_id'
  has_many :comments
end

class Post
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

You could declare the routes as:

```
resources :users do
  scope module: :users do
    resources :posts, only: [:index]
    resources :comments, only: [:index]
  end
end

resources :posts do
  resources :comments, module: :posts, only: [:index, :create]
end

resources :comments, only: [:index, :destroy, :update]
```

Using the module option lets us destinguish between the controllers for a "base resource" and its nested representation:

```
class API::V1::PostsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /api/v1/posts
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    # ...
  end
  def destroy
    # ...
  end
  def update
    # ...
  end
end

# Represents posts that belong to a user
class API::V1::Users::PostsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /api/v1/users/:user_id/posts
  def index
    @user = User.eager_load(:posts).find(params[:user_id])
    respond_with(@user.posts)
  end
end
```

In some cases you will want to nest to nest the create action as well if the resources should be created in the context of another:

```
class API::V1::Posts::CommentsController < ApplicationController
  # PATCH /api/v1/posts/:post_id/comments
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
    respond_with(@comment)
  end

  # GET /api/v1/posts/:post_id/comments
  def index
    @post = Post.eager_load(:comments).find(params[:post_id])
    respond_with(@post.comments)
  end
end
```

Comment: Also the canonical CRUD actions (show, index, create, destroy, update) can be augmented with extra verbs but if you are ever using a synonym like `add` or `remove` or listing or nested resource with `def things`. You are doing it wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation, however with your last example, how will you wrap a create action with 2 contexts (model belongs to 2 others) ? Like in the Bonus question in my post. How to create a relation object when the 2 parents need to be present at once

Comment: You don't. Use the most important model as context and pass the other relations as params.

Comment: Ok ! Thank you very much ! If I get it right it should look like this: POST /api/v1/candidates/1/accounts?source_id=2.